# ¿Diseño de emails no salen bien en microsoft outlook?

Tags: html, css, email

Hice un diseño de un email, me salen bien en gmail y outlook web, lo hice con divs y estilos en line, saben si toca colocar algo especial? o inspeccionar ese correo por el software microsoft outlook?, el envio de correos le utilizo **phpmailer**.

Muestro el codigo de como hice el diseño del correo:

```
  <?php $route = 'url'; ?>
  <body>
    <div style="background: #a0d3d7;max-width: 650px;margin:0 auto;">
        <div style="margin: 40px 0 0 0;">
            <div style="float: right; width: 171px; margin: 33px 36px 0 0;">
                <img src="'.$route.'images/mailin/logo.png" alt="logo" style="width: 100%;" />
            </div><!-- logo -->
        </div><!-- div logo -->
        <div style="position: relative;top: -42px;">
            <div style="width: 588px; margin: 0 auto;">
                <img src="'.$route.'images/mailin/titulo-cum.png" alt="titulo" style="width: 100%;" />
            </div><!-- imagen titulo -->
        </div><!-- div titulo -->
        <div style="color:#002f86;margin-top: -77px;">
            <h1 style="text-transform: uppercase;letter-spacing: 0px;text-align: center;">'.$usuario.'</h1>
            <p style="margin: 5px auto 0 auto;line-height: 27px;position: relative;font-size: 21px;top: -14px;text-align: center;width: 90%;">
                Te deseamos un año lleno de felicidad y nuevas experiencias. 
                Por eso tenemos un regalo para ti en <b>Experiencias Allianz</b>, 
                porque no necesitas esperar 364 días para disfrutar 
                de momentos especiales. <br>
                <b>Codigo: </b>'.$codigo.'
            </p>
        </div><!-- div texto -->
        <div style="margin: 16px 0 0 0;">
            <a href="'.$route.'" target="_blank">
                <div style="width: 183px; margin: 0 auto;">
                    <img src="'.$route.'images/mailin/boton.png" alt="boton" style="width: 100%;" />
                </div><!-- imagen boton -->
            </a>
        </div><!-- div botton -->
        <div style="margin: 0;">
            <div style="width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;">
                <img src="'.$route.'images/mailin/imagen.jpg" alt="cumpleaños" style="width: 100%;" />
            </div><!-- umpleaños -->
        </div><!-- div cumpleaños -->
        <div style="margin: -4px 0 0 0;">
            <div style="width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;">
                <img src="'.$route.'images/mailin/footer.png" alt="footer" style="width: 100%;display: block;" />
            </div><!-- footer -->
        </div><!-- div footer -->
        <!--div style="margin: 0;">
            <div style="width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;">
                <img src="'.$route.'images/mailin/imagen-footer.jpg" alt="footer" style="width: 100%;" />
            </div>
        </div>< div footer -->
    </div><!-- section -->
</body>
```

Imagen gmail

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Imagen outlook web

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Imagen micorsoft outlook

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Yo siempre pelée con el diseño de emails. Ahora no me complico y uso [mjml](https://mjml.io/) que es una librería para crear emails. Tiene una [aplicación para escritorio](https://mjmlio.github.io/mjml-app/) para ver en tiempo real el resultado. Quizás te sirva.

Comment: Toma en cuenta que la vista en las aplicaciones web (GMail, Outlook Web) depende del navegador que estés utilizando.  Mientras que en el aplicativo de escritorio Outlook muy probablemente utilice el motor de Internet Explorer que tengas instalado.  Y también deberías probar cómo se ve en dispositivos móviles (iOS, Android)

Comment: @Xint0 ya lo visualize en internet explore y me sale bien, sabes si hay una manera de inspecionar el codigo de microsoft outlook, tambiem intente con mjml como dijo  Gustavo García .

Comment: Para ser sincero, con MJML solo tienes que usar las etiquetas personalizadas de ellos y este se convierte a HTML ya estilizado de forma lo más compatible posible. En mi proyecto actual lo uso para generar emails, incluyendo imágenes, botones, boletines, etc., y se ve bastante bien en GMail, Outlook y Yahoo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Cuando hagas código para envío de correos masivos, utiliza "ancient code", es decir, todos los estilos in-line, lo más artesanal posible.
2. En el siguiente enlace encontrarás referencia a HTML compatible: https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/email-client-css-support/
3. Si buscas un framework CSS para realizar esto de mejor manera: http://zurb.com/playground/responsive-email-templates donde te muestra una tabla de compatibilidad.

Comment: Hola, no sabes si hay una manera de inspeccionar el código en microsfot outlook? traté mjml y sale mal

Comment: click derecho en el correo, ver fuente.

Answer (score 0):

Como te comenta fredyfx, date un repaso a esos enlaces son muy interesantes. Siempre va a haber un poco de variación entre gmail, outlook, thunderbird... etc etc, pero bueno, cuando mas a lo "standar" vayas, mejor.

Mira el tamaño de las imágenes, lo tienes en width: 100%, cámbialo al tamaño de la imagen porque parece que outlook no te coje el tamaño del div. Define tambien en  la tipografía y el tamaño para evitar que salte en outlook, por ejemplo:

```
<body style="font-size:15px; color:#ffffff; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; background-color:#f4f4f4">
```

Esto es una cuestión personal pero, los mailings con tablas dan muchos menos problemas... por desgracia aun muchos usuarios van con clientes de correos obsoletos... Un saludo!