# Correos enviados con PHPMAILER no respetan las dimensiones establecidas

Tags: php, html, css, phpmailer

Estimados estoy utilizando la librería PHPMAILER para el envío de correos desde mi hosting, eh hecho diferentes pruebas y eh conseguido enviar los correos de forma correcta con sus respectivas imágenes incrustadas, mi problema es que al definir las dimensiones de los **DIV** en las etiquetas **style**, al llegar al correo (escritorio), no se respetan dichas dimensiones, si establezco un DIV con una anchura de 800px, en el correo sigue ocupando el 100% de la ventana, cosa que no ocurre con las imágenes que si llegan con la dimensión establecida

Adjunto el código

```
<?php
require dirname(__FILE__).'/vendor/autoload.php';


use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

$mail->Host = 'xxxxxxxxx';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);
$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Username = 'xxxxxxx';
$mail->Password = 'xxxxxxx';

$mail->setFrom('xxxxxxxxx', 'Soporte EcuService Chile');
$mail->Subject = 'Correo de Confirmación | Portal EcuService Chile';
    
$mail->Body    = '
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" style="margin:0;paddin:0;width:800px;display:block;position:relative">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv=»Content-Type» content=»text/html; charset=iso-8859-1″>
    <title>Correo de Confirmación | Portal EcuService Chile</title>
</head>
<body>
    <body style="@font-face{font-family:"Jura";src: url("http://localhost/ecuservicechile/recursos/fuentes/Jura-Light.ttf")};font-family: "Jura"; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%">
        <div style="padding: 30px; border: 3px dotted #000; color: #000; width: 100%; position:relative">           
            <p>Estimado/a Jonathan Alarcón muchas gracias por registrarse en nuestro Portal de Archivos Tunning, su cuenta ha sido creada exitosamente, puede iniciar sesión con las siguientes credenciales de acceso una vez que su cuenta allá sido verificada.</p>
            <br>
            <br>
            <p style="border-bottom:1px dashed #FFF"></p>
            <p style="padding:10px 0"><strong>Usuario: </strong>xxxxxxxx</p>
            <p style="padding:10px 0"><strong>Contraseña: </strong>xxxxxxx</p>
            <p style="border-bottom:1px dashed #FFF"></p>
            <br>
            <br>
            <p>Para activar su cuenta, haga clic en el siguiente enlace:</p>
            <p>https://www.ecuservicechile.cl/portal/validar.php?correo=jonathan.alarcon.c@outlook.com&key=123456789101112131415</p>
            <br>
            <br>
            <p>Agradecemos su registro y le damos la más cordial bienvenida.</p>
            <p>Atte. Equipo EcuService Chile | contacto@ecuservicechile.cl</p>
            <img  style="padding-top:10px"src="http://localhost/ecuservicechile/imagenes/logo-negro.png" alt="" width="300">
        </div>
    </body>
</body>
</html>
';
$mail->addAddress('xxxxxxxxx', 'Jonathan Alarcón');


$mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

Comment: El problema no es PHPMailer, en correos electrónicos, el HTML no sigue el estándar, cada cliente de correo lo renderiza a su manera...

Comment: Revisa esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/64615/822 hay una pregunta muy similar, quizás te sea de ayuda. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente los clientes de correo no son navegadores web. Si bien pueden existir clientes de última generación que adapten ciertas cosas, el hecho es que ni soportan CSS3, ni HTML5, ni quieren hacerlo, su objetivo no es abrir páginas web completas desde un correo para que inyecten de manera directa códigos y cosas inesperadas.

Dicho eso, los clientes de correo tienen sus propias propiedades y para entenderlo, se han anclado a CSS2 y no al completo. Fíjate en este enlace que aunque dice que es para el office 2007, sigue siendo lo mismo para office 2016