# No se me visualiza formato html en la aplicación de outlook

Tags: html, c#, asp.net-mvc

Tengo una app donde al momento de hacer una acción, inmediatamente se envia un correo con detalles de dicha acción. Y esos correos ya tienen un formato predeterminado para una mejor visualización.

Así es como me llegan.

[image]

Pero al momento de abrir esos correos en la aplicación de outlook no se ve como debería de verse en el navegador...

Este es el metodo que utilizo para darle formato con todo y campos

```
private string notificarReasignacion(Solicitud solicitud, string agenteSolicitante, string correoPara,  string tituloCorreo, string pieDeCorreo, string Motivo)
        {
            try
            {
                Mail mail = new Mail();

                mail.Subject = tituloCorreo;

                string cuerpo =
                            "<style> th{width: 200px;} td,th{border: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255); padding: 10px border-color: black;}" +
                            "td{text-align: left;}" +
                            "th[scope='col']{background-color: rgb(25, 150, 25); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); border-color: black; font-size: 11px;}" +
                            "th[scope='row']{background-color: darkblue; color: white; text-align: right; border-color: black; font-size: 11px;}" +
                            "table{border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid rgb(200, 200, 200); letter-spacing: 1px; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 0.8rem; width: 100%;} </style>" +
                            "<body>" +
                            "<table>" +
                            "<tr> <th colspan='3' scope='col'>Información del Cliente</th> </tr>" +
                            "<tr> <th scope='row'> Empresa: </th> <td> Servicios Integrales GL7 SA de SV </td> </tr>" +
                            "<tr> <th scope='row'> Nombre del Usuario: </th> <td>" + solicitud.Contacto.Nombre + "</td> </tr>" +
                            "</table> <br/>" +
                            "<table>" +
                            "<tr> <th colspan='3' scope='col'>Información de Solicitud</th> </tr>" +
                            "<tr> <th scope='row'> Folio: </th> <td>" + solicitud.SolicitudId + "</td> </tr>" +
                            "<tr> <th scope='row'> Titulo: </th> <td>" + solicitud.Nombre + "</td> </tr>" +
                            "<tr> <th scope='row'> Descripción: </th> <td>" + solicitud.Descripcion + "</td> </tr>" +
                            "<tr> <th scope='row'> Prioridad: </th> <td>" + solicitud.SolicitudPrioridad.Nombre + "</td> </tr>" +
                            "<tr> <th scope='row'> Agente que solicita: </th> <td>" + agenteSolicitante + "</td> </tr>" +
                            "<tr> <th scope='row'> Motivo: </th> <td>" + Motivo + "</td> </tr>" +
                            "</table> <br/>" +
                            "</body>";

                mail.Body = cuerpo + pieDeCorreo;

                mail.Para.Add(correoPara);

                u.EnviarCorreo(mail);

                return "Se envió correo de notificación al agente";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return "Error al enviar correo de notificación al agente";
            }

        }
```

Y al momento de tener todos los campos me envia a otro controlador donde tengo una funcion que se encarga de enviar todos los correos a sus destinos.

```
public JsonResult EnviarCorreo(Mail mail)
        {
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            string correos = string.Join(",", mail.Para);
            try
            {
                SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com", 587);

                smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("x", "x");
                smtpClient.Port = 587;
                smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;

                MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();

                mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("x", "Mesa de Servicios");

                foreach (string p in mail.Para)
                {
                    mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(p));
                }
                foreach (string cc in mail.Copia)
                {
                    mailMessage.CC.Add(cc);
                }

                mailMessage.To.Clear(); //  <----------------------------------------------------
                mailMessage.CC.Clear(); // enviar correo de confirmación a reasignar solicitud
                mailMessage.To.Add("x"); // <--------------------------------------------

                mailMessage.Subject = mail.Subject;

                mailMessage.Body += mail.Body;

                mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

                smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Correo enviado a: " + correos + " - exitoso.");
                return Json(new { result = "success" });

                //ViewBag.Message = "Your Message submitted successfully. " +
                //" We will contact you shortly. Thank You";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Correo enviado a: " + correos + " - fallido. Error: " + ex.Message);
                return Json(new { result = "error" });
                //ViewBag.Message = ex.Message.ToString();
            }

            //return View();
        }
```

Nota: quite los correos institucionales para evitar cualquier filtrado de información privada en su lugar puse unas X.

Comment: Si se ven bien en el  navegador y mal en el outlook, es que es problema de este último.  Tienes que buscar una configuración que te permita ver el mensaje como html.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Diseño de emails no salen bien en microsoft outlook?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/64569/dise%c3%b1o-de-emails-no-salen-bien-en-microsoft-outlook)

Comment: Lo checare, gracias