# ¿Por qué no se refleja mucho el diseño HTML en los correos cuando envió un correo desde C#?

Tags: html, c#

buenos días, tardes o noches, a quien corresponda.
Como tal si conozco de HTML, y también tengo noción de que para darle diseño al texto en un correo electrónico se utiliza este y mas en especifico el HTML mas arcaico (aunque he de admitir que no recuerdo mucho de este "HTML arcaico"). Pues lo que quiero hacer es enviar una tabla con unos registros a un correo electrónico, tengo este código en C# el cual es el que utilizo para recopilar los registros, y acoplarlos a un HTML de un table.

```
 private void ultraButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            var allRowsEnumerator = ultraGrid1.Rows.GetRowEnumerator(GridRowType.DataRow, null, null);
            foreach (UltraGridRow childRow in allRowsEnumerator)
            {
                Yuyuko = Yuyuko + 1;
            }

            Medicine = new int[Yuyuko];
            Maribel = "Para quien corresponda, estos son los Incoming a los cuales hay que hacerle revisión, en este caso hay pendientes: " + Yuyuko + " por revisar. <br/>  \r\n" +
                "<table border: #b2b2b2 1px solid;>";
            Maribel += "<tr>";
            Maribel += "<th><b>No. de Incoming</b></th>";
            Maribel += "<th><b>Factura</b></th>";
            Maribel += "<th><b>Orden de Compra</b></th>";
            Maribel += "<th><b>Linea</b></th>";
            Maribel += "<th><b>Material</b></th>";
            Maribel += "<th><b>Proveedor</b></th>";
            Maribel += "</tr>";
            foreach (UltraGridRow childRow in allRowsEnumerator)
            {
                Medicine[Suwako] = Convert.ToInt32(childRow.Cells["IdIncoming"].Value);
                Maribel += "<tr>";
                Maribel += "<td>"+ Youmu +"</td>";
                Maribel += "<td>" + Convert.ToString(childRow.Cells["Factura"].Value) + "</td>";
                Maribel += "<td>" + Convert.ToString(childRow.Cells["OC"].Value) + "</td>";
                Maribel += "<td>" + Convert.ToString(childRow.Cells["Linea"].Value) + "</td>"; 
                Maribel += "<td>" + Convert.ToString(childRow.Cells["Material"].Value) + "</td>";
                Maribel += "<td>" + Convert.ToString(childRow.Cells["Proveedor"].Value) + "</td>";
                Maribel += "</tr>";
                
                Renko += Convert.ToString(childRow.Cells["IdIncoming"].Value) + ", ";
                Youmu = Youmu + 1;
                Suwako = Suwako + 1;
            }
            Maribel += "</table>";
            if (Yuyuko == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No ha colocado ningun Incoming para el correo");
            }
            else
            {
                //Parte sin mucha importancia (según yo), aquí solo lo envió a otro lado, para preparar todavía el mensaje, para poner su destinatario y asunto.
                Renko = Renko.Remove(Renko.Length - 2);
                Yukari = Maribel;
                Reimu= Renko;
                Ringo = Yuyuko;
                sendOfButton = true;

                this.Close();
            }
        }
```

Les adjunto el como es que llega el correo electronico.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo arcaico es no usar hojas de estilo, el atributo [`border`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table#border) es obsoleto desde hace mucho tiempo.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Diseño de emails no salen bien en microsoft outlook?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/64569/dise%c3%b1o-de-emails-no-salen-bien-en-microsoft-outlook)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que un correo en HTML se pueda ver "correctamente" en todos los clientes de correo (sean basados en web como Gmail, Outlook.com) o los respectivos clientes de escritorio, app mobile, etc... es una tarea ardua realizarla "manualmente". Ya que no es una simple pagina HTML porque no te permite colocar un script o estilos sino que deben estar en etiquetas style (ni tampoco tendremos todos los estilos disponibles)

Te puedes ayudar, y es la recomendacion, que utilices Frameworks CSS que tiene "exlusivos" template para los "mailing"
Ejemplo **Foundation for Emails**

> Use Foundation for Emails to design responsive HTML emails that work in any email client.

- https://zurb.com/playground/responsive-email-templates
- https://get.foundation/emails.html
- https://get.foundation/emails/docs/

Que puedes ver los templates (tanto para descargar como preview)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y los test que se realizarn en cada cliente de correo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si bien no esta especificamente tablas. Hay formas con el "grid" de armar este tipo de "layout" (en los ejemplos puedes encontrar algo similar a lo  que necesitas.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guía.

Answer (score 0):

A diferencia del CSS aplicado en páginas web, el envio de elementos HTML por correo no son tan compatibles con formatos CSS avanzados de hecho algunos solo llegan a los que se hacían para el HTML1.

Te recomiendo que cualquier elemento ya sea una tabla, un h1 un div o lo que sea, formatees el estilo directamente en el elemento:

Ejemplo:

```html
  <table style="border: 1px solid #b2b2b2; color: blue;">
    <tr>
      <th style="border: 1px solid #b2b2b2;"><b>No. de Incoming</b></th>
      <th style="border: 1px solid #b2b2b2;"><b>No. de invoice</b></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="border: 1px solid #b2b2b2;"><b>123</b></td>
      <td style="border: 1px solid #b2b2b2;"><b>345</b></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

#### ACLARATORIA: Esto solo aplica para el envío de correo para hacerlo compatible con cualquier manejador de correo, el HTML tratado para páginas web se usa CSS con mejores prácticas, tal cual como lo explican en el link que te dejo aqui abajo (w3schools).

#### Para refrescar el conocimiento de HTML y CSS te recomiendo visitar https://www.w3schools.com